# How to send bulk mails avoiding spam?

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, bulk

My problem is: We have got a lots of users and they got about 6-10k e-mails per day. Those e-mails for reset passwords, or registration confirmation, etc.

But our IP is on a BAN list or what is that. So we can't send e-mail to a lots of users, they can't confirm their changes.

I already tried PHP MAIL with smtp solutions, but Gmail or Joomla ban us in short time. How many mails or how should I send them? It's a big problem to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third party provider, you'll avoid a lot of headaches, and it's generally very cheap.

[Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), [Sendgrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) or [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) are popular choices, but there are tons of them on the market.